# Automatically compute mnemonic charachers for menu items

Tags: algorithm

Menu mnemonic characters are underlined characters which can be pressed for quick selection of containing menu items using a keyboard. Identifying mnemonic characters is usually done by humans and should be done separately for each translation of the program.

I need an algorithm which given a set of strings representing menu items should automatically calculate unique for each item mnemonic characters.

For example given menu items "AAB" and "AAA" it should suggest "B" as mnemonic character for the "AAB" and "A" as mnemonic for "AAA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a library mnemonicsetter for solving this problem (https://github.com/dpolivaev/mnemonicsetter) . It works fast but it can not always find the optimal solution.